# Specify input for password manager autofill

Tags: html, input

I have a form with multiple inputs, but when autofilling, the password manager always enters data in the first input above the password. Can I tell it to enter data in a specific input?

Code example:

```
<input placeholder="Your email" type="email"/>
<input placeholder="You fb id" type="text" />
<input placeholder="Your password" type="password"/>
```

Comment: Which password manager? What does it fill into the input?

Comment: @xehpuk chrome password manager, which contains username(email) and password. When I focused on password field, chrome displays small dropdown with available accounts for this page. If I click on one of them, it puts username(email) data to fb id input.

Comment: This is an autofill function of chrome. You need to change the chrome settings if necessary

Comment: @Ken Lee I know. I'm looking for a way to control the inputs it fills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution!!!! If you add an onChange event to the field that is above the password field and accepts automatic login fill, it will fill data in the field specified in js. Here is code example:
HTML:

```
<input placeholder="Your email" id="userEmail" type="email" />
<input placeholder="You fb id" id="fbId" type="text" />
<input placeholder="Your password" type="password" />
```

JS:

```
const fbId = document.querySelector("#fbId");
fbId.onChange = () => {
  document.querySelector("#userEmail").value = fbId.value;
};
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Oh, I see now. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome might think that your email and text inputs are the same, so it auto fills both of them. So, we are going to put an irrelevant "type" on one of the inputs.

```
<input placeholder="Your email" type="email"/>
<input placeholder="You fb id" type="url" />
<input placeholder="Your password" type="password"/>
```

We set the email type to email, fb id to url, and password type to password.

Comment: This doesn't work, but I've found solution.